# How to remove a WordPress action which uses the current object - $this?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm familiar with `remove_action` when removing an action in WordPress.

To create the action:
`add_action( 'action_hook', 'function_name', 10, 3 );`

To remove the action:
`remove_action( 'action_hook', 'function_name', 10, 3 );`

But how can I remove an action which uses the current object? e.g `$this`

```
add_action( 'some_action_hook', array( $this, 'some_function' ) );
```

Ref:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Inside class**

```
add_action( 'some_action_hook', array( $this, 'some_function' ) );
```

**Outside class**,

With use of global vairable:

```
global $my_class;
remove_action( 'some_action_hook', array( $my_class, 'some_function' ) );
```

Using class name:

```
remove_action( 'some_action_hook', array( 'MyClass', 'some_function' ) );
```

*[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)*.

Comment: Hi Rikesh - thank you for this. Which approach would you recommend? Using the global var or using the class name?

Comment: Using class name. [Read Why use of globals are bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why).

Answer (score 4):

To extend on Rikesh answer: Sadly, using class name will not work. As it says on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

> If an action has been added from within a class, for example by a
>   plugin, removing it will require accessing the class variable.

This leaves only:

```
global $my_class;
remove_action( 'some_action_hook', array( $my_class, 'some_function' ) );
```

Or in case of a singleton class like Jetpack to remove the 'show_development_mode_notice' hook (for example) like this:

```
remove_action( 'jetpack_notices', array( Jetpack::init(), 'show_development_mode_notice' ) );
```

Comment: NB: If the function is static you can call the class and function directly.

Answer (score 1):

Using the class name as suggested by the accepted answer didn't work for me in WordPress 4.5.

You can use these code snippets to remove the action (don't mind it being called "filter" on the project's page) by passing the method name or (a bit safer) the class name and method name: https://github.com/herewithme/wp-filters-extras/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13284360)

Comment: Yes - if the code snippet is short. In this case, it's a plugin, so posting the whole source code and docs here doesn't seem to be a good idea. It's forked 11 times, so it won't vanish easily. Sometimes a link is the proper solution.

Comment: Nobody says that a link is bad. But there is no problem to add the a useage example of the plugin here too. You should not pase all source and examples here.

Comment: Okay, so why was my answer deleted when it's the only currently working answer? Because someone says that a link to a project is not enough, even though the project has clear usage examples on the front page? Seriously, think about your decisions before making such a call. You can downvote or comment all you want, but deleting a legit answer is not helping anyone.